# Amazon EC2 gives internal server error when posting via Python

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, python, json

I have a problem with python API and MY ec2 instance. When I am trying to post a json I am getting an error like

> 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 
>   {"error_message": "Sorry, this request could not be processed. Please
>   try again later."}

I have one more ec2 instance with same configuration like this one and that one works very fine with out any problem. Can any one help me in finding a solution for this

Json Data format is as given below

```
{
 "job_position":"Test Postion thomas1235",
 "eligibility_course_id":["1","2","3","4"],
 "eligibiltiy_course_ids":["1","2","3","4"],
 "eligibility_branch_id":["5","6","7","8"],
 "eligibiltiy_skill_ids":["10","23","24"],
 "location":["26","30","2","3"],
 "job_category":["1","4","7"],
 "sms_category":"1",
 "posting_date":"31/07/2014",
 "expiry_date":"31/08/2014",
 "job_type_id":"1",
 "job_type_other":"",
 "hiring_process":["1"],
 "job_description":"Test Description<\/p>",
 "company_name":"Test Company name",
 "company_profile":"Test company profile<\/p>",
 "company_url":"",
 "seo_title":"Test Seo Title",
 "seo_description":"Test Seo Description",
 "seo_keyword":"Test seo Keyward",
 "response":"1","how_to_apply":"",
 "terms_agreement":"1",
 "specify_terms_agreement":"",
 "employer_id":"1008369",
 "button_submitForm":"Post Job",
 "posted_by_id":"114",
 "template_name":"job_description"
}
```

pip freeze give me this o/p in both instances

```
Django==1.4.3
MySQL-python==1.2.4
amqp==1.0.13
anyjson==0.3.3
argparse==1.2.1
billiard==2.7.3.31
boto==2.34.0
celery==3.0.20
django-extensions==1.1.1
django-s3-cache==1.4.2
django-storages==1.1.8
django-tastypie==0.9.14
kombu==2.5.13
lxml==3.4.4
mimeparse==0.1.3
mock==1.0.1
phpserialize==1.3
python-dateutil==2.1
redis==2.7.6
requests==1.1.0
six==1.3.0
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

this configuration is same in both the servers. Pls help me for a solution error log is not showing any error. :(